# lambda expression to get first value where

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am running this query

```
dr[0] = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(l => l.Field<int?>("ID") == "5")
    .Select(l => new {k = l.Field<int?>("description")})
    .First()
    .ToString();
```

I am trying to get the description where id = 5. But it is giving error

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

What is wrong with this query ?

Comment: What is the data type of `dr`?

Comment: It is a 'datarow' which is to be filled in gridview

Comment: are you sure that ID is `int?` and not just `int` type?

Comment: You are comparing `int?` to a `string`. Change `"5"` to `5`

Comment: Are you sure `description` is of type `int?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your field types - For "ID" you are comparing int to string... for "description" you are casting to an int which also doesn't look correct.

Comment: That was the problem. Such a silly mistake I did. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Glad I could help! Have done similar things on many occasions :)